# Shuffling without Arrays

Tags: javascript, html

I posted this question yesterday, but deleted as I had to fix my code to make it much more neat. But for my assignment, I have to make a quiz in JavaScript, but I also have to make it so that whenever the user retakes the quiz, the questions and answer choices are shuffled, meaning in a different order. I have seen examples of this on the website before, but they placed their choices and questions in arrays, and I did my quiz without arrays. Is there still a way to do this? Thank you.

This is the JS code (I can not put it in a JSFiddle because it says that the code needs to be pure JS):

```
function gradeTest() {

   //variables with global implications
   var totalPoints = 18;
   var numberOfPoints = 0;
   var numberofQuestions = 0;
   var alertText;
   var i;
   function multipleChoice(idOfQuestion, answer, idOfText) {
        var select = document.getElementsByName(idOfQuestion);
        for(i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
            if(select[i].checked) {
                if(select[i].value == answer) {
                    numberOfPoints++;
                    numberofQuestions++;
                    changeColor(1, idOfText);
                    break;
                }
            } else { changeColor(0, idOfText) }
        }
    }
   var a1 = document.getElementById('q1').value.toLowerCase();
   if(a1 == '<script>') {
      numberOfPoints = numberOfPoints + 2;
      numberofQuestions++;
      changeColor(1, 's1');
   } else { changeColor(0, 's1') }
   var a2 = document.getElementById('q2').value.toLowerCase();
   if(a2 == '//') {
      numberOfPoints = numberOfPoints + 2;
      numberofQuestions++;
      changeColor(1, 's2');
   } else { changeColor(0, 's2') }
   multipleChoice('q3','false','b1')
   multipleChoice('q4','true','b2')
   multipleChoice('q5','false','b3')
   multipleChoice('q6','true','b4')
   multipleChoice('q7','popup','m1')
   multipleChoice('q8','false','m2')
   multipleChoice('q9','2','m3')
   multipleChoice('q10','10','m4')
   multipleChoice('q11','inner','m5')
   multipleChoice('q12','11','m6')
   multipleChoice('q13','5','m7')
   multipleChoice('q14','slash','m8')
   multipleChoice('q15','no','m9')
   multipleChoice('q16','11','m10')
   if(numberOfPoints == totalPoints) {
      alertText = "Congratulations! You got all the questions right!";
   }
   else {
    if(numberOfPoints > 5) {
      alertText = "You got " + numberOfPoints + " out of " + totalPoints + " possible points! You also got " + numberofQuestions + " right!";
    }
    else {
      alertText = "You got " + numberOfPoints + " out of " + totalPoints + " correct. And that means you got " + numberofQuestions + " right.... Know your javascript more..."; } }
   alert(alertText);
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<form id="test">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="table">
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "s1" name="short">Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript?</td>
<td>
<input id="q1" maxlength="30" name="q1" size="30" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "s2" name="short">What do you use for line comments?</td>
<td>
<input id="q2" maxlength="30" name="q2" size="30" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "b1" name="boolean">'document.getElementById' is not a valid Javascript Request.</td>
<td>
<input name="q3" type="radio" value="true" />
        True |
<input name="q3" type="radio" value="false" />
        False</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "b2" name="boolean">Javascript is case-sensitive.</td>
<td>
<input name="q4" type="radio" value="true" />
        True |
<input name="q4" type="radio" value="false" />
        False</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "b3" name="boolean">There is no such Math object in Javascript.</td>
<td>
<input name="q5" type="radio" value="true" />
        True |
<input name="q5" type="radio" value="false" />
        False</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "b4" name="boolean">"1" + 2 + 4 evaluates to "124"</td>
<td>
<input name="q6" type="radio" value="true" />
        True |
<input name="q6" type="radio" value="false" />
        False</td>
</tr>
<tr> <!-- check -->
<td class="set" id = "m1" name="mult">What does 'alert' do?</td>
<td>
<input name="q7" type="radio" value="popup" />
      Creates a popup window based on text. |
<input name="q7" type="radio" value="reminder" />
      It sets a reminder. |
<input name="q7" type="radio" value="command" />
      It sets an in-built command to alert the user about a certain function being performed. |
<input name="q7" type="radio" value="none" />
      None of these</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "m2" name="mult">What is the result of '(true + false) > 2 + true;'?</td>
<td>
<input name="q8" type="radio" value="true" />
      true |
<input name="q8" type="radio" value="false" />
      false |
<input name="q8" type="radio" value="error" />
      TypeError |
<input name="q8" type="radio" value="none" />
      None of these</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "m3" name="mult">What is the result of '"1" - - "1";'?</td>
<td>
<input name="q9" type="radio" value="1" />
      1 |
<input name="q9" type="radio" value="2" />
      2 |
<input name="q9" type="radio" value="11" />
      11 |
<input name="q9" type="radio" value="none" />
      None of these</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "m4" name="mult">'function() {
    var a = 10;
    if(a > 5) {
        a = 7;
    }
    alert(a);
}'
What is the value that will be alerted?</td>
<td>
<input name="q10" type="radio" value="7" />
      7 |
<input name="q10" type="radio" value="null" />
      null |
<input name="q10" type="radio" value="10" />
      10 |
<input name="q10" type="radio" value="undefined" />
      undefined</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "m5" name="mult">What do you use to change HTML?</td>
<td>
<input name="q11" type="radio" value="inner" />
      .innerHTML |
<input name="q11" type="radio" value="change" />
      .changeHTML |
<input name="q11" type="radio" value="html" />
      .HTML |
<input name="q11" type="radio" value="doc" />
      .documentChangeHTML</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "m6" name="mult">var price1 = 5;<br>
var price2 = 6;<br>
var total = price1 + price2;</td>
<td>
<input name="q12" type="radio" value="11" />
      total = 11 |
<input name="q12" type="radio" value="56" />
      total = 56 |
<input name="q12" type="radio" value="colon" />
      total = 5;6; |
<input name="q12" type="radio" value="none" />
      None of The Above</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "m7" name="mult">var x = "'ABC'"</td>
<td>
<input name="q13" type="radio" value="3" />
      x.length = 3 |
<input name="q13" type="radio" value="5" />
      x.length = 5 |
<input name="q13" type="radio" value="22" />
      x.length = 22 |
<input name="q13" type="radio" value="none" />
      None of The Above</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "m8" name="mult">How do you insert special characters into a string in JS?</td>
<td>
<input name="q14" type="radio" value="//" />
      // |
<input name="q14" type="radio" value="slash" />
      \ |
<input name="q14" type="radio" value="&" />
      & |
<input name="q13" type="radio" value="nope" />
      You can't.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "m9" name="mult">Can objects be compared?</td>
<td>
<input name="q15" type="radio" value="no" />
      No |
<input name="q15" type="radio" value="yes" />
      Yes |
<input name="q15" type="radio" value="certain" />
      On certain circumstances. |
<input name="q15" type="radio" value="lol" />
      Objects don't exist.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="set" id = "m10" name="mult">What does 'document.write(5 + 6)' place in the HTML page?</td>
<td>
<input name="q16" type="radio" value="11" />
      11 |
<input name="q16" type="radio" value="duo" />
      5+6 |
<input name="q16" type="radio" value="56" />
      56 |
<input name="q16" type="radio" value="error" />
      TypeError</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<input onclick="gradeTest()" name="submit" type="button" value="Grade This Test" />
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT: There was a line of code that needed to be removed. It had no purpose.
EDIT: More code removed.

Comment: why can't you use arrays?

Comment: Could you narrow the scope on this question a bit? Would be helpful to have a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In other words: rather than posting all of your code, could you include just enough to reproduce the problem?

Comment: My teacher told me about the shuffling after I had completed the quiz this way. I don't know how I would be able to incorporate arrays this into the project.

Comment: Yes, I'll remove code that isn't needed.

Comment: I'd consider that a reason to refactor, then.

Comment: What is refactoring?

Comment: "Re-write your code in a significantly different way"

Comment: We're not interested in whether you deleted a line or not. That information is available via the history mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JavaScript solution to shuffle the elements inside a `parent` element for shuffling elements by tag name like `tr`.

```
function getRandom(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
}

function shuffleElements(parentElement, tag) {
    var tagsObj = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var tags = Array();
    //getElementsByTagName gives you an Object, so converting that to Array().
    for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(tagsObj).length;i++) {
        tags.push(tagsObj[i]);
    }
    var length = tags.length;
    var randomized = Array();
    //Randomize the elements of the tags array.
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        var random = getRandom(tags.length);
        randEl = tags[random];
        tags.splice(random,1);
        randomized.push(randEl);
    }

    //Put the randomized elements in the Parent.
    document.getElementsByTagName(parentElement)[0].innerHTML = '';
    var final = '';
    for(var i=0; i<randomized.length; i++) {
        final += (randomized[i].outerHTML);
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName(parentElement)[0].innerHTML = final;
}
```

So you can use the above function to randomize the elements inside your table like below-

```
shuffleElements('table','tr');
```

Here is a working Fiddle with your code - https://jsfiddle.net/jpfdsbhx/1/

PS - I changed the answer in your code from `<script>` to `script` to make it run with JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you for this! But one more question, sorry to disturb, but how would I be able to incorporate this by let's say using a button to refresh the page and running this shuffle function to change up the questions?

Comment: Actually never mind, I have figured it out. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @EshChhura Happy to help! :)